# How to get value of REST style parameter in Angular?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have an application in ASP.NET MVC. It use REST-style parameters. Address of one action is `http://app/Resource/Action/Id`.

In Angular we can access query strings using `$location.search()` or `$routeParams.search` or even `$window.location.search`. Though any of these methods can obtain query string parameters.

How can I access my Id parameter (without splitting `window.location.pathname`)?

Comment: In any case it will be a splitting. href.lastIndexOf('/') + 1) as you need to take the last parammetr.

Comment: Are you using UI Router?

Comment: @CallumLinington No I don't.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In your route configuration you can do this:

`$routeProvider.
      when('/:Resource/:Action/:Id', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/your-partial.html',
        controller: 'YourCtrl'
      })`

you can then use `$routeParams` to access the properties you require as follows:

`var resource = $routeParams.Resource;
var action = $routeParams.Action;
var id = $routeParams.Id;`

Comment: this is mostly correct, but use `$routeParams` when using angular router, `$stateParams` only works with ui.router and `$stateProvider`.

Comment: ah yes, corrected the $routeProvider, but forgot to edit the $stateParams. Thank you for the heads up, editing now